# Rest API authentication

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, authentication, oauth

I need to use the **SharePoint Rest API** from a **custom JavaScript application** (outside from SharePoint).
How can I **authenticate the user** to use the Rest API. 
I can not deploy a SharePoint app, I need those web services from my app.
I need to access to SharePoint on premise data.

Comment: I'm not convinced you can't use something like provider-hosted app. However if you want to hack around you could use a proxy.

Comment: So is there no way to call API from outside SharePoint?

Comment: None of the APIs will let you do CORS AFAIK, which makes me think of using a proxy. Why can't you just use the token you get from `TokenHelper` in a provider-hosted app and then just route all REST requests through your provider-hosted app? I would imagine you could just pass requests

Comment: This discussion would help you [Update items using REST API from outside](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134300/updating-sharepoint-item-using-rest-api-from-outside-of-sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that such a scenario is now possible: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-web-apps-using-CORS-to-access-files-in-Office-365

[image: How to authenticate external app]

Disclaimer: I have not tested this scenario yet..

Comment: This is quite nice. Does it only work with Azure AD? What about "plain" 365, and on-premise?

Comment: You will need Azure AD or ADFS (on-premise AD) to create OAuth tickets for authentication.. without this, it will not know how to issue tickets and coordinate authentication among different parties..