# Sharepoint access to API

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-foundation, ajax, jquery-ajax

I was asked to develop a program that extracts the properties of each user profile. I'm using ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio and I'm trying to use AJAX and Javascript to do the requests. Here's my code.

```
<script>
        var url = "https://[...]";

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("button").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url + "/_api/web/lists",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/jsonp; odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),

                    },
                    success: function () {
                         alert("success");
                     },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //Add these parameters to display the required response
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(xhr.responseJSON);
                        },
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
    <button class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
```

However, like this, I can't access the API, as it returns a 403 error. How can I pass on my credentials so it recogninzes my login and what do I need to change here so I get a successful request?

Also, do I need to pass the script to a Sharepoint Add-in for this to work?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this definitely a cross-domain request?  According to [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/134353/8992), apparently SharePoint does not support JSONP/CORS.  If it is just a request to a different site/site collection/web app/server/etc, but _is_ within the same domain, I do have some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Rest API has not exposed such an endpoint to enumerate all users. '_api/web/siteusers' only list all users related to this site.

Below is a workaround about how to search all users in Local People Result:

- [Sharepoint: Search Query to get People Directory using Rest API](https://xenrcode.net/2015/09/08/sharepoint-search-query-to-get-people-directory-using-rest-api/)