# Cross domain call using Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, cors

I saw an article that we cannot do cross domain calls with SharePoint Rest API [Updating SharePoint item using REST API from outside of SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134300/updating-sharepoint-item-using-rest-api-from-outside-of-sharepoint).

In my case, my app is hosted in azure web app. The SharePoint domain and app domain both are different.

Can I call the SharePoint site using Azure Graph API?